# What does it mean for a matrix to be nearly singular?

Tags: terminology, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently enrolled in numerical analysis course, and a term I have not heard of came up: *nearly singular matrix*.

I know that a non-singular matrix is one where the column vectors are linearly independent.

My guess is that a nearly singular matrix is one where one of the column vectors $v$ can be "almost" represented as a linear combination of other column vectors of the matrix, but I am really not sure.

Also, why are we concerned with nearly singular matrix in numerical computation? (The term never came up in my linear algebra class, so I assume it has no significance in terms of theoretical aspect.)

Comment: A(large)Hilbert matrix is an example of an ill conditioned matrix and polynomials can be ill conditioned too. A condition number is computed, a big condition number means the matrix will respond less well to arithmetic operations performed on it than one with a smaller condition number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more common term for nearly singular matrix is *ill-conditioned*. If a matrix has a large [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) then it is called ill-conditioned. Computations involving ill-conditioned matrices are usually very sensitive to numerical errors.